# Why does physics "make sense"?

Tags: soft-question, perception

I was wondering if anybody had an explanation for why physics makes so much sense to us humans. In physics, many concepts just seem to make sense to me, but I cannot explain why. You may say that this means I do not understand the concept, but I do not think that that is true: I feel confident that I could explain these concepts in a way that other humans agree would make sense.

As an example, when I describe the position of an object with a vector, that just makes sense. I cannot think of any other way to describe it. Similarly, the concept of a field (gravitational, electrical, etc.) just makes sense to me: I can visualize a force that acts on a particle depending on its location.

I guess my question is, why do these concepts make sense to humans? Why can we trust our physical/mathematical intuition? How can we be sure that, when we pass our laws of physics down to future generations, these concepts will "make sense" to them in the same way (i.e. they will not misuse them)? Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: Is your question "why does physics make sense" or "why does math make sense"? Because, by and large, the reason physics makes sense is because math makes sense.

Comment: Related: [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences) by Eugene Wigner.

Comment: I think it is only classical physics that "makes sense" to most humans because it can be seen in every day Life, like a ball rolling down a hill or wind pushing an object across the ground. By and large physics isn't required to follow human intuition (e.g. quantum mechanics which is highly unintuitive).

Comment: "*Similarly, the concept of a field (gravitational, electrical, etc.) just makes sense to me: I can visualize a force that acts on a particle depending on its location.*" I am surprised that you feel that gravitational fields make sense. I find it a very odd thing that if you put two lonely objects in space, they will attract each other. How does one even know that the other is there? Once, forces-acting-over-distance were explained by use of a concept called *the ether*, that made okay sense, but was later abandoned. Nowadays the field concept is used - but for me tough to make intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if anybody had an explanation for why physics makes so
>   much sense to us humans.

It doesn't.

I think by "physics" you mean "classical mechanics". Because if you've studied quantum mechanics, you would not make this statement. QM is so utterly at odds with your everyday experience that it will make your head explode. It has made some very smart people do some very dumb things due entirely to the fact that it makes no sense at all to us humans.

If you go back in time you'll find there were a number of radically different interpretations of various sciences that "made sense" that were completely wrong. For instance, we used to widely believe that disease was caused by misty, stagnant air, which is why everyone got diseases when they went to Africa and India. This is where the name "malaria" comes from, French for "bad air". Now you would think this is stupid, but at the time you would believe it and say it makes "perfect sense".

For physics, simply consider Aristotle. He stated that the natural state for objects on the ground was to lie still. Anything moving was due to an animated object making it move, that being animals and people. So if you push on a block of wood it comes to a stop, so it "makes sense" that wood is not animate and thus its natural state is to be still.

Of course there were inanimate things that moved, apples do fall of trees on their own. So that's where the four elements come in. Apples are clearly mostly a mix of some ground and water. Objects naturally want to be in "their sphere", so the apple falls out of the air because it's in the wrong sphere - it's in the air and wants to be on the ground. Smoke rises because it's mostly air so it wants to go up. And the planets and stars keep rotating because the "unmoved mover" started their spheres in motion, and things in the heavens don't work like they do on earth, obviously.

Makes sense right?

Then along comes Newton. He says this is bogus. First of all, the natural behaviour of objects is to do whatever they are already doing = if they're moving they want to keep moving. It's only because of friction that they stop. Planets don't move because the heavens are somehow "different", they move because there's nothing to stop them.

And objects that move on their own? There is an invisible force known as gravity that pulls on things. This single force is why apples fall off trees, and why planets move. There's no crystal spheres, no earth wind and fire, just gravity and mass, and absolutely everything in the universe is subject to it - after all it's the Universal Law of Gravitation right?

Makes sense, right?

So here we have two theories that disagree fundamentally with each other at every turn, but they both make sense. And so I would say physics doesn't make sense, and that if a particular interpretation seems to, you simply haven't looked hard enough for the edge cases.

**Update:**

While typing I thought of another way to think of this.

What is an earthworm's concept of physics, especially gravity? I'm not sure it even has one. I doesn't have eyes, so it can't see things falling. It doesn't get above the ground enough to fall on its own. All it knows is that there is an infinite flat plane with food on top of it, and an infinite volume below the plane to move in. I suspect they can feel up and down, but they may not interpret this as a force pushing them, but more as a sort of "brightness" or "color", with up being different than down, but not due to any sort of "force".

So then we ask, why does the physics of an earthworm make so much sense to us earthworms?

Answer (score -1):

It's because we made physics with our senses that physics make sense.
Physics didn't fall from heavens, we humans made physics. The laws were there for sure, but the symbols we used for expressing the laws were created for the very purpose of human reasoning.

Just like when people ask "why do math work in physics", that is simply because they were created for that very purpose.

-Why is that fork so convenient for eating food ?

-Why do we count using base 10 ? That is so intuitive :D :D

Comment: What do you mean by the laws where there? Are you sure that the universe is using laws to behave?

Comment: yes, I am. Do you have examples where it doesnt have rules? Or perhaps you think the rules arent there when we stop looking?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_realism